# Error: "Trying to get property 'name' of non-object" when accessing user name in Blade view

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to get name of a user using the following code, but i'm getting an error. please help. The error is

**"Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: /var/www/html/laravel/imarker/resources/views/student/exams/available.blade.php)"**

```
@foreach($availableExams as $exam)
     @foreach($exam->user as $user)
           {{($user->name)}}
     @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Exam Model

```
 public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

User Model

```
public function exams(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Exam');
}
```

Controller

```
public function availableExams(){
    $users = User::all();
    $availableExams = Exam::all();
    return 
view('student/exams/available',compact('availableExams', 'users'));
   }
```

Comment: when i `dd($user)` it returns **true** instead of the name. what could be the name?

Comment: yes, because user method has relationship belongs to so it returns only one record, try to dd $exam->user in view you will get an idea.

Comment: why use two foreach?If each exam belongsTo one user you need one foreach in view..`{{$exam->user->name }}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each `Exam` has one `User` and that `User` has a name? Try this:

```
@foreach($availableExams as $exam)
    {{$exam->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: this is crazy. when i `{{dd($exam->user->name) }}` i get the name, but once i use `{{$exam->user->name}}` i get the same error **Trying to get property 'name' of non-object (View: ...**

Comment: @TimothyMach when you use `dd($exam->user->name)` what's dump exactly?copy please

Comment: @mohammadHosseini I get "Mach Turor" - which is what I want.

Comment: Something is funky. Can you try {{ $exam->user()->first()->name }}

Comment: @Anders the problem was checking if a user exists. ` {{$exam->user->name ?? 'No tutor found'}} ` Thats how i solved it. Thanks so much. you gave me a hint

Answer (score 0):

Got it. One user was missing. using an if statement to check if the object exists solves it. Using 2 arrows risks finding an empty item/object and that causes problems, hence the need for the condition clause. Thank you guys.

```
@foreach($availableExams as $exam)
    {{$exam->user->name ?? 'No tutor found'}} 
 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

Update your blade file.

```
@foreach($availableExams as $exam)
           {{ $exam->user()->first()->name }}
@endforeach
```